# PHP Curl: SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)

Tags: php, curl, ssl, https

I'm trying to execute HTTPS request:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://***.com');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiesFile);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$out = curl_exec($curl);
```

After request, $out is empty, and I'm getting this log:

```
* About to connect() to ***.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying *.*.*.*...
* connected
* Connected to ***.com (*.*.*.*) port 443 (#0)
* error:14077458:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)
* Closing connection #0
```

Why?

Comment: whats your platform and version of php and openssl? check `phpinfo();`

Comment: The **first hit on Google** points back to a question here on SO that explains why this happens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619706/running-curl-with-openssl-0-9-8-against-openssl-1-0-0-server-causes-handshake-er - how's that for poor research.

Comment: @fvu, thanks, curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); worked for me.

Comment: @Waygood, PHP 5.4.10, OpenSSL/0.9.8x, Mac OS X 10.8.4

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Fix:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. just to add to this, as it is better to leverage SPL defined constants like this: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3);`

Comment: error:SSL: couldn't create a context: error:140A90C4:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_new:null ssl method passed

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PRTG and get this error, go to settings and change from "SSL V2 or V3" to "SSL V3".