# Copy Image from Remote Server Over HTTPS

Tags: php, image, http, https, copy

I already find answers how to copy images over HTTP, but when I try to copy images over HTTPS then I get this:

> Warning: copy(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error
>   messages: error:14077458:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)

This is code I use:

```
copy('https://www.metalacmarket.com/product-img/org/JpUSP3KgvgeeikNheRDi4CRg.jpg', IMAGES_PATH.'JpUSP3KgvgeeikNheRDi4CRg.jpg');
```

Any idea how to get images over HTTPS?

Comment: I added sample code...

Answer (score 2):

You could use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Here's an example adapted from the [basic curl example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php).

```
$source = 'https://www.metalacmarket.com/product-img/org/JpUSP3KgvgeeikNheRDi4CRg.jpg';
$target = 'image.jpg';

$ch = curl_init($source);
$fp = fopen($target, "wb");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Good idea, but now I get this error: error:14077458:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)

Comment: You be able to get this to work by setting some cURL options. Check out this question: [PHP Curl: SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191672/php-curl-ssl-routinesssl23-get-server-helloreason1112)