# Why this rss feed cannot be imported by any rss reader?

Tags: ssl, rss

I cannot import this rss feed:

https://mwager.de/feed.xml

On the w3c validator I get the following error:

```
Server returned [Errno 1] _ssl.c:490: error:14077458:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)
```

From: http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmwager.de%2Ffeed.xml

**Edit:**

I can import the localhost URL though using rss reader app "NetNewsWire":

```
http://localhost:4000/feed.xml
```

I just don't get why I can view the feed in a browser but no reader can import it. So this seems like a ssl issue but I have no idea how to tackle this problem...

**Edit 2:**

If I remove the "force SSL option" on my hosting providers website, it works with the non-ssl URL: http://mwager.de/feed.xml but still not with https://mwager.de/feed.xml

Comment: "Debug my web site" questions with only a link to the site are likely to be closed because as soon as you've fixed the problem the question becomes useless for anyone having the same problem later. For instructions on how to improve the question see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: thx, but I don't know how to isolate the problem here. It seems there is a problem with forced SSL cert of my provider but I am no expert in this area. With a browser I can open the feed: https://mwager.de/feed.xml but no rss app can import it.

Answer (score 1):

If the validator sees no problem with your http:// feed, then it's a valid feed.

The problem with SSL is that the validator (and maybe the feed readers you're testing?) are using a version of libssl that isn't compatible with your host's. From what I gather it's an openssl bug: [Running curl with OpenSSL 0.9.8 against OpenSSL 1.0.0 server causes handshake error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619706/running-curl-with-openssl-0-9-8-against-openssl-1-0-0-server-causes-handshake-er)

See this question for a different example of the same situation, with php-curl: [PHP Curl: SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191672/php-curl-ssl-routinesssl23-get-server-helloreason1112)