# SSL error when cloning from a https repository using msysgit due to openssl curl

Tags: git, curl, openssl, msysgit

When trying to clone from a https repository  I get the following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://xxx/': error:14077458:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)
```

According to [this](http://marc.info/?l=openssl-dev&m=136760073921954&w=2) this is caused by a problem in openssl/curl which does not properly handle warning level alerts in SSLv23. On the commandline passing `-3` to curl sovles the issue.

How can I tell git to "pass" `-3`to `curl` while cloning?

**Additional Information**

- I use msysgit: git version 1.8.4.msysgit.0
- with OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
- Settign http.sslVerify to false does **not** solve my problem (the connection does not reach this point and bails out before).
- I could reproduce the problem with `curl`:

.

```
$ curl -v https://xxx/
* Adding handle: conn: 0x13dc6e8
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x13dc6e8) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to xxx port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 1.2.3.4...
* Connected to xxx (1.2.3.4) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
  * error:14077458:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)
  * Closing connection 0
  curl: (35) error:14077458:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)
```

and passing the `-3`option fixes the issue:

```
$ curl -v -3 https://xxx/
* ...
* Connected to xxx (1.2.3.4) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
  * SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
  ...
```

*Edit*

The server is running with OpenSSL 1.0.1e  11 Feb 2013 which points to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619706/running-curl-with-openssl-0-9-8-against-openssl-1-0-0-server-causes-handshake-er)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a SVN-Repository.

Using

```
git svn clone https://xxx
```

instead of

```
git clone https://xxx
```

solves the problem.

Edit:
As it seems that I am not the only one who forgot the "svn" , I just want to add that this is also the answer if you get

```
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

as an error.