# Workaround for "SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)" serverside (Openshift)?

Tags: ssl, curl, openshift, handshake

When running a handshake from a OpenSSL 0.9.8 client against OpenSSL 1.0.0 it seems that this might cause a "SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:reason(1112)" error.

See [Running curl with OpenSSL 0.9.8 against OpenSSL 1.0.0 server causes handshake error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619706/running-curl-with-openssl-0-9-8-against-openssl-1-0-0-server-causes-handshake-er) for a discussion.

The solution for a client seems to be to force SSL V3 instead of V2 or V3.

Yet, I am the server in the connection running on OpenShift with Apache. I do not have access to `ssl.conf` and the Apache logs as it seems.

Is there any workaround for me to change the configuration in OpenShift or to bypass the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the [OpenShift bug tracker](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=975369#c7):

> On further exploration, there doesn't appear to be a mechanism which allows the mod_rewrite based Apache front-end to handle SNI on the primary application address (name-domain.rhcloud.com).  SNI is handled properly with aliases that supply their own SSL certificates.

Result: It is not possible to receive SSL connections by clients using strict SNI when using *.rhcloud.com and not a custom domain with own SSL cert.